# Programatically set the Environment version for RollbarSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rollbar

I'm using [Rollbar Sharp](https://github.com/mroach/RollbarSharp)

Just to let you know: Rollbar allows any string to be used as an identifier in the "Environment" setting

The manual instructs you to add:

```
<add key="Rollbar.AccessToken" value="YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"/>
<add key="Rollbar.Environment" value="dev{version}"/>
```

However this is not ideal as I need to be able to set `Rollbar.Environment` on app startup to include the app version number as the version for the application gets bumped from other means and don't want to have to manually change the web.config every time.

Would prefer to avoid having to edit the web.config on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this using OwinStartup by setting and then retrieving the version in Assembly, omitting the Environment setting from the web.config and setting the `DefaultEnvironment` dynamically like so:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string version = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();

RollbarSharp.Configuration.DefaultEnvironment = version;
```